# Socket.io get socket id from client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to get the socket identifier and send it to my PHP application.
But I can't figure out how to get it.
In my HTML I have :

```
<script>
    //connection to socket.io
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.20:48972');
    console.log(socket.io.engine);
    console.log(socket.io.engine.id);
</script>
```

Here the result of the two "console.log". We can see the "id" property in the first one, but I get undefined if I try to access it directly.

Is there any way to do it ? Or is it meant to not be accessed ?
[image: Results of console.log]

Comment: Probably the `id` property is added between the time you log `socket.io.engine` and the time you expand the object in the console. (On a `connect` event, perhaps?)

Comment: Well that was it, it works. If I do a `console.log(socket.io.engine.id)` in the `socket.on('connect')` event, the id is set. Thank you very much.
Although it's weird that the console.log is updated in real time in the chrome console.